# Is it possible to build 5 sub modules in one single job which have different script to execute?

Tags: jenkins

I want to know how can we parameterize build in jenkins. I need to create a jenkins job which will contain 5 sub jobs in it. i need to create a drop down , selelct any of the module and build it. But the script used is different for every sub build? can any1 guide on the same is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

`string` parameters in `Jenkins` result in environment variables of the same name.

So, you could write a wrapper script in `bash` which would look for the environment variables that could be set as a result of the parameterized build (i.e. your 5 sub-jobs) in a series of `if-elif` statements, and within each one, you would invoke the necessary build script from there.

The build script that you would have `Jenkins` run would be the wrapper script.